# Getting exception in Android Studio

Tags: android

Every time in my android studio I am getting below exception plz help me

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: can you post your gradle code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable multi dex , you cant have more than 65k methods inside your app ,To enable multi dex do this

in app level build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.ebook"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true

}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

 }
```

you can find full documentation over [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)